# DataView.RowFilter with timespan in c#

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

I have trouble doing rowfilter with timespan to a specific time. I don't want solution with linq thingie..

```
dv.RowFilter = "timeField = '11:00:00'";
```

Is there any symbol to represent time like in datatime? 
e.g.

```
dv.RowFilter = "datetimeField = #12/31/2002#";
```

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40286094/492336

Answer (score 2):

According to the post on link below: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/079eb08f-80e2-4d3b-8b8c-8d2027fde370/timespan-data-type-in-datatableselect?forum=adodotnetdataset

when converting TimeSpan to string is "PT11H???????????????" Where the number 11 is the hour. I'm still don't know where the minutes and seconds are placed in the string.

so my code is written something like this

```
dv.RowFilter = "Convert(timeField, System.String) LIKE 'PT11H%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

> It'll hit this exception 'Cannot interpret token ':' at position 45.'

It sounds like the expression is expected to be localized:

```
dv.RowFilter = "timeField = '11.00.00'";
```